# Why am I getting an error in this code that says, The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am creating a project for a class using C# lists. I made the project and when I ran it I am getting errors for the list Music. It is saying that in my EditSongInList that where I am using music it does not exist. It is also saying that in two of my methods they do not exist int he current context. I think that it could be stemming from one thing or just a misplaced word but I am a beginner in C# and have tried to do what I can but there is a lot of errors. Here is the code. I am putting all the code due to me not knowing exactly where the problem is coming from.

Program.cs

```
using static MyMethods;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my list example.");

        // This creates a list
        List<Music> songList = new List<Music>();
        // adds the overloaded constructor
        Music testSong = new Music();
        songList.Add(testSong);

        // call our PrintMenu
        int option = 0;
        while(option !=6){
            option = PrintMenu();
            if (option == 1){
                PrintSongList(songList);
            }
            if(option ==2){
                EditSongInList(songList);
            }
            else if (option == 3){
                AddSongToList(songList);
            }
            else if (option == 4){
                RemoveSongFromList(songList);
            }
            else if (option == 5){
                AddSongToList(songList, true);
            }
        }
    }

    // PrintMenu() displays options to user and returns their selections
    // Must return an Integer
    static int PrintMenu(){
        Console.WriteLine("Choose one of the following options:");
        Console.WriteLine("1.) Print the song list");
        Console.WriteLine("2.) Edit a song on the list");
        Console.WriteLine("3.) Add a song to the list");
        Console.WriteLine("4.) Remove a song from the list");
        Console.WriteLine("5.) Insert a song on the list at a specific position");
        Console.WriteLine("6.) Exit");
        // return integer:
        return ReadInteger("Enter your selection", 1, 6);
    }     

    // PrintSongList takes the songs and prints the songs in the music list for the user
    static void PrintSongList(List<Music> mList)
    {
        // check to see if theres anything to print
        if(mList.Count == 0){
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there are no songs available. Please add a song to continue.");
        }
        // use foreach loop to print each song in the list
        int i = 0;
        foreach(Music m in mList){
            Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {m}");
            i++;
        }
    }

    // AddToList() takes the music list and boolean, and promts the user for information and adds it to the list at a specific location
    static void AddSongToList(List<Music> mList, bool insertOption = false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You chose to enter a song.");
        // prompt user for information
        Console.Write("Enter the song name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        double songLength = ReadInteger("Enter the number of seasons");

        int rating = ReadInteger("Enter the rating", 1, 5);

        int releaseDate = ReadInteger("Enter the release year", 1750, 2023);

        // while loop to get current song information
        bool topHundred = false;       // initialize outside of loop
        bool done = false;

        while(!done){
            done = true;                // lets us exit the loop if we don't change it back to false
            Console.WriteLine("Has this song been on the billboard 100? (Y/N): ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            
            if(input == "Y"){
                topHundred = true;
            }
            else if (input == "N"){
                topHundred = false;
            }
            else{
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter only \"Y\" or \"N\".");     // makes it so if they type somoething other than Y or N it tells them.
                done = false;
            }
        }


    // RemoveSongFromList() promp the user to select a songs on the list and remove it
    static void RemoveSongFromList(List<Music> mList){
        if(mList.Count == 0){
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there are no songs available. Please add a song to continue.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose from the following songs to remove:");
        PrintSongList(mList);
        int number = ReadInteger("Enter a song to remove", 1, mList.Count) - 1;
        // remove song from the list at number
        mList.RemoveAt(number);
    }

    // EditSongInList() display the list of songs, prompt the user to pick a song, and then prompts
    // user to select a data member and edit the information
    static void EditSongInList(List<Music> mList){
        Console.WriteLine("Please select from the following songs to edit:");
        PrintSongList(mList);
        // prompt the user to pick a song to edit
        int Music = ReadInteger("Enter your seletion", 1, mList.Count);

        // Call PrintEditMenu() to choose which data member to change
        int option = 0;
        while(option != 6){
            option = PrintEditMenu();

            if(option == 1){
                // edit name
                Console.WriteLine($"The name is currently {mList[music -1].GetName()}");
                Console.Write("Enter a new name: ");
                mList[music -1].SetName(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine($"The name is been changed to {mList[music -1].GetName()}");
            }
            else if (option == 2){
                // edit song length
                Console.WriteLine($"The song length currently is {mList[music -1].GetSongLength()}.");
                mList[music - 1].SetSongLength(ReadDouble("Enter the new length of the song."));
                Console.WriteLine($"The length of the song has been changed to {mList[music -1].GetSongLength()} minutes.");
            }
            else if (option == 3){
                // edit the release date
                Console.WriteLine($"The current rating is {mList[music -1].GetReleaseDate()}.");
                mList[music -1 ].SetReleaseDate(ReadInteger("Enter release date", 1750, 2023));
                Console.WriteLine($"The release date has been changed to {mList[music -1].GetReleaseDate()}.");
            }
            else if (option == 4){
                // edit the rating
                Console.WriteLine($"The current rating is {mList[music -1].GetRating()}/5.");
                mList[music -1 ].SetRating(ReadInteger("Enter release date", 1, 5));
                Console.WriteLine($"The rating has been changed to {mList[music -1].GetRating()}.");
            }
            else if (option == 5){
                // edit if the song has been on the top 100
                Console.WriteLine($"The currently {mList[music -1].GetTopHundred()} on the top 100 chart.");
                Console.Write("Is the song on the top 100 chart? (Y/N): ");
                // if the user enters "y"/"Y" we will current to true
                mList[music -1].SetTopHundred(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");
                Console.WriteLine($"The song has been updated to song that it {mList[music -1 ].GetTopHundred()} on the top 100 chart.");
            }
        }
    }

    // PrintEditMenu() prints the options to edit and returns the user selection
    static int PrintEditMenu(){
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose from the following options: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Edit song name");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Edit song length");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Edit the release date");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Edit the songs rating");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Edit if the song has been on the top 100");
        Console.WriteLine("6. Return to the menu");
        return ReadInteger("Enter your selection", 1, 6);
    }
}

}
```

Music.cs

```
class Music{
    // data members
    string name;
    double songLength;
    int rating;      // out of 5 
    int releaseDate;
    bool topHundred;          // true if making it was on the top 100

    // constructors
    public Music(){
        name = "Test Song";
        songLength = 2.45;
        rating = 5; // out of 5
        releaseDate = 2023; // year
        topHundred = false;
    }

    // overloaded constructor
    public Music(string n, double sL, int r, int rL, bool tH){
        name = n;
        songLength = sL;
        rating = r;
        releaseDate = rL;
        topHundred = tH;
    }

    // Getters and setters
    public string GetName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void SetName(string n){
        name = n;
    }

    public double GetSongLength(){
        return songLength;
    }
    public void SetSongLength(double sL){
        songLength = sL;
    }

    public double GetRating(){
        return rating;
    }
    public void SetRating(int r){
        rating = r;
    }

    public int GetReleaseDate(){
        return releaseDate;
    }
    public void SetReleaseDate(int rD){
        releaseDate = rD;
    }

    public string GetTopHundred(){
        if(topHundred){
            return "has been";
        }
        else{
            return "has not been";
        }
    }

    public void SetTopHundred(bool tH){
        topHundred = tH;
    }

    // ToString
    public override string ToString(){
        return $"{name} is a {songLength} minute song that was released in {releaseDate}, it has a rating of {rating}/5, and it {GetTopHundred()} on the top 100 billboard.";
    }
}
```

MyMethod

```
class MyMethods{
    // ReadInteger display a prompt and validates that user entry is an int
    public static int ReadInteger(string prompt){
        bool done = false;
        int number = 0;

        while(!done){
            done = true;    // exit the loop when condition are met
            try{
                Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
                number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch{
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid integer. Please try again.");
                done = false;       // repeat until integer is valid
            }
        }
        return number;
    }

    // ReadInteger(string, int, int) display promot to the user, validates the entry
    // is an integer between low and high values
    public static int ReadInteger(string prompt, int low, int high){
        bool done = false;
        int number = 0;

        while(!done){
            done = true;    // exit the loop when condition are met
            try{
                Console.Write($"{prompt} between {low} and {high}: ");
                number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch{
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a valid integer. Please try again.");
                done = false;       // repeat until integer is valid
            }

            // validates user entry is within the low and high range
            if(done){
                if(number < low){
                    Console.WriteLine("Number entered was too low. Please try again.");
                    done = false;
                }
                else if(number > high){
                    Console.WriteLine("Number entered was too high. Please try again.");
                    done = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return number;
    }    

    // ReadDouble displays a prompt to the user and validates their entry is a double
    public static double ReadDouble(string prompt){
        bool done = false;
        double number = 0.0;
        while(!done){
            done = true;    // exit the loop when all criteria is met
            
            try{
                Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
                number = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch{
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a double. Please try again.");
                done = false;
            }
        }
        return number;
        
    }

     // ReadDouble(string, double, double) displays a prompt to the user and validates their entry is a double
    // between given low and high values 
    public static double ReadDouble(string prompt, double low, double high){
        bool done = false;
        double number = 0.0;
        while(!done){
            done = true;    // exit the loop when all criteria is met
            
            try{
                Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
                number = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch{
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a double. Please try again.");
                done = false;
            }

            if(done){
                if(number < low){
                    Console.WriteLine("Number was too low. Please try again");
                    done = false;
                }
                else if(number > high){
                    Console.WriteLine("Number was too high. Please try again.");
                    done = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return number;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes must be `public`, like `public class Music`.

Comment: `Program`is the only exception, it does not need to be `public`.